# How to bind from DataTemplate to Page's DataContext?

Tags: binding, uwp, datacontext, uwp-xaml, template10

I've got a page where a DataTemplate is being used to bind to the model for that content, e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyDataType">
    ... content ...
</DataTemplate>
```

In that content, I need to be able to bind a Click event. I need that click event to exist in the view model that is set as the page's DataContext:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MyViewModel x:Name="ViewModel">
</Page.DataContext>
```

but I'm really struggling with getting it to compile. Every approach I try results in the compilation error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I know I can't use x:Bind because that will bind to the DataTemplate's DataContext, so I've been trying to use Binding and, based on other SO answers I've read, it *seems* like the answer should be:

```
Click="{Binding DataContext.Button_Click, ElementName=Page}"
```

where Page is defined as the x:Name for the Page. I've tried removing DataContext. I've tried adding ViewModel.

What am I misunderstanding? Is it not possible to do what I want to do? I've tried using code-behind instead but I'm using Template 10 and that pushes almost everything onto the view model, which makes it harder for me to access things like the navigation service from code-behind.

Comment: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Samples/Search/Views/MainPage.xaml.cs  There is always another way.  This is really old example but it shows some of the first ways that bindings were done with T10, with naming of the ViewModel in the codebehind, but instantiation was also carried into the view with the XAML markup.  Take a look at the view for MainPage as well.

Comment: Anotherway would be through Behaviors

Comment: @mvermef, first example is using `x:Bind`, which won't work inside a data template. Using a `Behavior` here is an overkill.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr; use Messaging.**

@justinXL is right, 'ElementName' *can* work. But is it best?

The problem you are trying to solve has already been solved with messaging. Most MVVM implementations include a messaging solution. Prism uses PubSubEvents; MVVM Light has its own messenger. There are others, too.

The idea is that an outside class, typically described as a `message aggregator`, is responsible for statelessly receiving and multicasting messages. This means you need to have a reference to the aggregator but not a reference to the sender. It’s beautiful.

For example

A common use case might be a mail client and how the data template of a message in the list would include a trash/delete button. When you click that button, what should be called? With messaging, you handle the `button_press` in the model and send/publish a message (one that passes the item).

The hosting view-model has subscribed to the aggregator and is listening for a specific message, the `Delete` message that we just sent. Upon receipt, it removes it from the list and begins the process to delete it from cache/database, or whatever – including prompting the user with “Are you sure?”

This means all your data binding in your data template is local, and does NOT extend outside its local scope. Why does this matter? Because if you use Element Binding to reach the hosting page, it means you cannot 1) move this template to a resource dictionary or 2) reuse this template.

There are two other reasons.

1. you cannot use compiled x:Bind to do this because it already limits use of this painful binding approach – this matters because a data template is typically in a list, and performance should always be prioritized, and
2. It adds considerable **complexity**.

Complexity?

I am a big fan of sophisticated solutions. I think they are rare and are the trademark of truly smart developers. I love looking at such code/solutions. Complex is not the same as sophisticated. When it comes to complexity, I am not a fan. Data binding is already difficult to wrap your head around; multi-sourcing your data binding across scope boundaries is pure complexity.

That’s what I think.

Answer (score 2):

Your binding expression is correct, except it won't work with a `Button_Click` event handler. You will need an `ICommand` defined in your page's *ViewModel*.

Since you are using *Template10*, you should be able to create a `DelegateCommand` called `ClickCommand` like this

```
private DelegateCommand<MyDataType> _clickCommand;
public DelegateCommand<MyDataType> ClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        _clickCommand = _clickCommand ?? new DelegateCommand<<MyDataType>>((model) =>
        {
            // put your logic here.
        });

        return _clickCommand;
    }
}
```

And the binding will be updated to

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ClickCommand, ElementName=Page}" CommandParameter="{x:Bind}" />
```

Note I have also added a `CommandParameter` binding to the button as you might want to know which `MyDataType` instance is associated with the clicked button.

Comment: Also note that if you define your `ClickCommand` inside your `MyDataType` class, you would be able to `x:Bind` to it directly. This is not a bad solution too.